# ExtJs:Send Radigroup name and value as parameters

Tags: extjs4

In my form i am using text field and radio groups and buttons as follows,

```
var radiogroup = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
                fieldLabel: 'Specimen ?',
                allowBlank: false,
                name:'isSpecimen',
                anchor: '85%',
                items: [
                    {
                    boxLabel: 'Yes',
                    name: 'radio',
                    inputValue: 'Y'
                 },
                {
                    boxLabel: 'No',
                    name: 'radio',
                    inputValue: 'N',
                    checked:true
                }
                ]                   
            });

var createOrderForm = new Ext.FormPanel({               
                renderTo: "createOrder",
                frame: true,                
                width: 500,                 
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Instruction',
                    name: 'instruction',
                    width: 300,
                    allowBlank:false
                },
                radiogroup,                     
                {
                            xtype : "textfield",
                            id : 'textfield1',
                            fieldLabel : "Type",
                            name : "type",
                            hidden:true,
                            width: 300,
                            disabled:true
                        }],
                        buttons:[{ 
                            text:'Create',
                            formBind: true,  
                            listeners: {
                                click: function(){
                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                        url : url+'/lochweb/loch/order/persist',
                                        params : createOrderForm.getForm().getValues(),
                                        success : function(response){
                                             console.log(response.responseText); //<--- the server response
                                             window.location = url+'/lochportal/viewSuccessForm.do';
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                            }]
            });
```

When i click **create button**,radio group name and value is not passed as parameter to url,but other control name and value are passing correctly.How to pass the radio group name and input value as paramater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the name and value (here you specify them as "Y"/"N") of the radio selected are sent. I suggest you remove the `name` of RadioGroup and set the names of the radios inside as "isSpecimen".

Comment: I mean: var radiogroup = new Ext.form.RadioGroup({
                fieldLabel: 'Specimen ?',
                allowBlank: false,
                anchor: '85%',
                items: [
                    {
                    boxLabel: 'Yes',
                    name: 'isSpecimen',
                    inputValue: 'Y'
                 },
                {
                    boxLabel: 'No',
                    name: 'isSpecimen',
                    inputValue: 'N',
                    checked:true
                }
                ]                   
            });